# TypeScript: Type Guard for custom type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

**Goal: Trying to create a type guard for a custom type.**

Here is my custom type:

```
type AppProviders =  'box' | 'dropbox' | 'google';
```

This is my first attempt in creating [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but this seems redundant in declaring allowed values twice:

```
type AppProviders =  'box' | 'dropbox' | 'google';
const appProviders: AppProviders[] = [ 'box', 'dropbox', 'google' ];

function isAppProviders(provider): provider is AppProviders {
    return appProviders.includes(provider)
}
```

Is there a better way of doing a type guard for custom literal types?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases

> `type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";` 
> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value **a string must have**. In practice string literal types combine nicely with union types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features together to get **enum-like** behavior with strings.

I had to look this up.... the example I found was https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20200619-StringLiteralTypeGuardInTypescript.html

```
export const APP_PROVIDERS = ['a', 'b'] as const;
export type AppProviders = typeof APP_PROVIDERS[number];

export function isAppProviders(unknownString: string): unknownString is AppProviders {
  return (APP_PROVIDERS as unknown as string[]).includes(unknownString);
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm partial to `(APP_PROVIDERS as string[]).includes(key)` since it's more expressive of what you're doing (`key` might not be an `AppProviders` but the elements of `APP_PROVIDERS` are definitely all `string`s), but the general approach is the one I'd recommend